# Is there a way to retrieve the app "Released on" & "Updated on" date from the play store in a flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-play

I am trying to print some of the data in my about page. And two values are important. I need to retrieve and print the Released on and Updated on dates from the play store in my flutter app, so is there away to read those from the play store. Check the attached screenshot to understand about which values I am speaking.

[image]

I tried to use the package_info_plus library to do that but it helped me only to retrieve the app version and some other data but not the dates. Is there any other library or a workaround to do that?

Thanks